# Need help refactoring some duplicated Java code. Interface or Generics or some other solution?

Tags: java, generics, refactoring

I have some Data Objects e.g. `Task`, `Resource` etc.

These Objects hold domain data e.g.

```
public class Task{
   private int Id;
   private String taskName;
.......
  //getters and setters here

//in addition they have a special method dynamically to get values i.e. There is a reason for this

         public static String runGetter(Task task, String getter) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
                for (Method method : task.getClass().getMethods()) {
                    if (method.getName().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(getter.toLowerCase())) {
                        if (method.getReturnType().isPrimitive()) {
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.append(method.invoke(task));
                            return sb.toString();
                        }
                        if (method.invoke(task) != null) {
                            return method.invoke(task).toString();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

        }
}
```

Now I have some methods that take these objects and write them out to streams

e.g.

```
public class WriterUtil{

    public void write(Task task, File outputFile){
    //write the task object out.
```

}

public void write(Resource resource, File outputFile){
            //write the resource object out
            }

```
        ....
```

}

The write methods call another method to get data out of the object as follows. (Yes, it can be made more efficient but it is not the core of my problem)

```
public class WriterUtil {
.....

    public static String extractLine(Task task, LinkedHashMap<String, String> columns, String delimiter) throws IllegalAccessException,
                IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Iterator<String> itr = columns.keySet().iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String getter = "get" + itr.next();
                String value = Task.runGetter(task, getter);
                if (value == null)
                    value = "";
                sb.append(value + delimiter + " ");
            }
            return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.lastIndexOf(delimiter)).trim();
        }
......


}
```

My Main problem is this given the described scenario above, I find myself writing the same identical code for each domain object e.g.

public void write(Task task, File outputFile)
public void write(Resource resource, File outputFile)
//etc ....

I repeat the same for extractLine.
As you can see I am duplicating the same code for each domain object. Where the only thing varying is the actual domain object. These methods do the exact same thing with each domain object.

My Question is; if I am to refactor these methods and write one method each to apply to every domain object, what are my best options.

1. Should I have the domain objects implement an interface? This seems rather cumbersome and I am not sure it is the right course of action.
2. Can I use generics? I expect it is probably the best practice but I have very limited experience with how to go about generifying (Is that a word?) my Domain Objects and these common methods. Can someone offer a re-write of my above code on how they would modify them for generic?
3. Do I have a third option?

Comment: Why not add a `write(OutputStream)` method to your `Task` class? What domain objects are the problem? Running a Task and getting its' output? Why not add `toString()` to `Task`. What is the question?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ maybe more appropriate

Comment: Static access to the class like `Task.runGetter(..` is basically destroying any attempt to make it generic or handle it via interfaces because the decision what method to call is done at compile time. You need it dynamic at runtime. I must also agree with @ElliottFrisch : Every Object knows about it's internal state. Don't put code that duplicates that knowledge into another class. Your writer needs to know how to write, not how to access the internals of a `Task`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The Domain Objects values are written out in column delimited. The columns written can vary, the delimiters can vary and the rules that determine what and how it should be written out are complex.

Comment: @RomanVottner. That is a good suggestion. I was wondering whether that is better than Using an Interface Instead of Object.

Comment: @Zapi the run getter can be updated to be dynamic. The actual Writer classes only know how to write. WriterUtil is used by writers.. The Writers pass the domain to WriterUtil and get back a line. How the writer writes as I said before is determined by other factors

Comment: I would pass a format pattern to a write in the `Task`. Or implement different `Task` Decorator(s) to perform the write differently.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch  Good idea, format patterns and decorators are a solid option. I will check it out and if the work needed stacks better with what I would gain with interfaces and possibly go that way. I am also now more inclined towards and interface for the domain objects as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the reflection code into a utility type and change the signature to:

```
public static String runGetter(Object bean, String getter)
```

The `Task` type isn't used at all inside the method.

Likewise, the only reason you need a `Task` type here is because the other call requires it:

```
public static String extractLine(Object bean, Map<String, String> columns,
                                                                String delimiter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an interface; generics can't be employed here (you could do it in C++ with templates, but not in Java).

If you don't want you objects to implement the interface, you can create helper objects for each of your domain classes; those helper objects would implement an interface with the `extractLine()` function:

```
class TaskExtractLine implements IExtractLine
{
  public TaskExtractLine(Task task)
  {
    this.task = task;
  }

  public String extractLine(LinkedHashMap<String, String> columns, String delimiter)
      throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
  {
    return WriterUtil.extractLine(task, columns, delimiter);
  }

  private Task task;
}
```

Then you'll have the write function like this: `public void write(IExtractLine extractLineHelper, File outputFile)` and call it like this: `write(new TaskExtractLine(task), outputFile)`.

Comment: I think my best option in this scenario is use and interface. I was leery of going in that direction for domain objects but it seems to be the better of all the choices. Thanks

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, you don't have to add interfaces to **domain objects**, you can create helper objects instead.